# Drop in sessions and revenue in DV360 reports in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, dv360

We relaunched our website a couple of months back and since then the sessions and revenue data reported for DV360 insertion orders has fallen to 10% of it's pre-launch numbers. While the numbers reported in Display channel within Channel reporting has not been affected. dbm/cpm as source/medium within Display Channel has remained consistent. The impressions numbers have not changed.

We use auto-tagging to for both AdWords and DV360 systems. We had turned it off and went to utm tags but it didn't help the issue.
On the landing page I see the correct dclid parameter and which is also sent in the /collect request to the google-analytics servers.

I'm seeing 2 warnings from the gtm.js library in Chrome browser console which could be related to this issue but I didn't find any information about them online.These are the errror messages:

```
unrecognized feature:'attribution-reporting'
unrecognized feature: 'conversion measurement'
```

Please see the screenshot. We have enabled "enable display advertising features" in Google Tag Manager.
[Chrome Developer Tools warning sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoC2n.png)

Could anyone point to probable reasons for this drop in DV360 and how to fix it?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. You should delete this question here and ask it there.